# How to create this button that show different forms?

Tags: vb.net

I want to create a windows form that will show forms inside a form  like in the Image. Is the controls in the image are actually buttons or it is a `Tab Control`? Everytime I clicked on every button, more forms are stacking. Please help...

Thank you in advance..

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please update your post to include code you are working with, what isn't working and expected outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Way too much to post actual code, but the idea is as such:

1. Create your buttons with a Flat appearance, and put them into a FlowLayoutPanel. Style the Buttons to get your flat look-n-feel. Alternatively, you can use a regular Panel and dock the buttons Left.
2. Create your forms that will act as "tab pages", and set the TopLevel property to False, BorderStyle to None, and DockStyle to Fill, for each one. NOTE: The VS IDE does not expose the TopLevel property in the Properties page (don't confuse it with the TopMost property that is exposed), so you have to set TopLevel in code when instantiating the Form.
3. Now you have two options: Load all your forms in to Panel, that represents the "content area" and set the .Visible property false for each one except the one you want to show. Or, you can add and remove new instances of the form to the Panel if reloading the form isn't particularly cumbersome, each time one of your menu Buttons are clicked.

Note that yours in an extremely `broad` question, and could be subject to closure.